# Extract text of all child nodes of a specific parent node as a variable in a data frame using Rvest

Tags: r, xml, rvest

I have an xml document that has a structure like so

```
<ClassificationNode>
    <District id = "8">
        <code>1A</code>
        <Name>LALD1</Name>
        <Zone id = "21254">
            <E1>OU29</E1>
        </Zones>
    </District>
    <ClassificationNodeChildList count = "2">
       <ClassificationNode>
            <District id = "8.1">
               <code>1B</code>
               <Name>LALD1A</Name>
               <Zone id = "213">
                   <E1>OU54</E1>
               </Zones>
             </District>
             <District id = "8.2">
               <code>1C</code>
               <Name>LALD1C</Name>
               <Zone id = "214">
                   <E1>OU65</E1>
               </Zones>
             </District>
     </ClassificationNode>
   </ClassificationNodeChildList>
</ClassificationNode>
```

I would like to get a data frame that looks like so:

```
district_id   code  Name    Zone_id   E1
8             1A    LALD1   21254     OU29
8.1           1B    LALD1A  213       OU54           
8.2           1B    LALD1B  214       OU65
```

I would like to avoid looping if possible. Seems like this would be pretty straightforward (and it probably is) but I am stumped.

I have tried:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

x <- "pathtolocalxmlfile.xml"

district_id <- x %>% 
      read_xml() %>% 
      xml_find_all('//District') %>% 
      xml_attrs() %>% 
      data.frame()
```

and this gives me the district ids and

```
Nodes <- x %>% 
      read_xml() %>% 
      xml_find_all('//District') %>% 
      xml_text()
```

Gives me the text of each child node under the district node but as a collapsed string. Any ideas on how to efficiently coerce the data into a data frame.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you start with tag `Zone` but end with `Zones` -> modify the ending tags to `Zone`.
Then read and implement this code:

```
library(rvest)
pg <- read_xml("pathtolocalxmlfile.xml")
district_id <- pg %>% xml_find_all("//District") %>% xml_attr("id")
code <- pg %>% xml_find_all("//District/code") %>% xml_text(trim = TRUE)
name <- pg %>% xml_find_all("//District/Name") %>% xml_text(trim = TRUE)
zone_id <- pg %>% xml_find_all("//District/Zone") %>% xml_attr("id")
E1 <- pg %>% xml_find_all("//District/Zone/E1") %>% xml_text(trim = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(district_id, code, name, zone_id, E1)
```

Output:

```
> df
  district_id code   name zone_id   E1
1           8   1A  LALD1   21254 OU29
2         8.1   1B LALD1A     213 OU54
3         8.2   1C LALD1C     214 OU65
```